# Validating the legitimacy of images (Malware / embedded XSS detection)

Tags: php, xss, penetration-testing

Our cloud system was recently subjected to a pen test. One of the flags raised in the report regarded an upload form which 'allowed uploads of arbitrary data'. Even once restricted to images (detected largely by extension and PHPs built in mime detection), they are still concerned about 1) hidden malware or 2) XSS attacks embedded in to the images themselves.

How is it possible to defend against these vectors?

Edit: the suggested duplicate is not applicable because -

An image with embedded XSS would still validate with usual checks (it could be hidden in the comment section of a gif file, for instance). Furthermore, checking the image size is already one of the checks done, but research will prove it is not reliable for such use.

Comment: An image with embedded XSS would still validate with usual checks (it could be hidden in the comment section of a gif file, for instance). Furthermore, checking the image size is already one of the checks done, but research will prove it is not reliable for such use.

Comment: how would the payload be executed on the server?

Comment: @Dragon by viewing/opening the image on the site

Comment: even if the *.jpg is raw javascript, it wont be run if you site uses <img src="really_java_script.jpg">

Comment: @Dragon I am not disagreeing - but do you have anything to back that up? And what about if you did <a href="link-to-image.jpg">View image</a> ?

Comment: test it your self, shoud take about 5 seconds

Comment: Depends on browser and version, no? I have read that old versions of IE, for instance, are quite susceptible to this type of attack.

Comment: if you use IE6 you deserve what you get.

Comment: @Dagon - sorry just realised I kept calling you Dragon :p .. I appreciate the sentiment, but pen testers are very anal and I don't think they will accept that. I'm starting to feel like they're taking the piss - either it's not a problem, or there's a way to deal with it, otherwise how would sites like facebook still be operating??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110446/discussion-between-alfie-and-dagon).

Comment: the issue is always execution, if you treat an image file like an image there is never any execution. If you extract something from it then, of course, you have to treat that like any other user input. There are vulnerabilities in older browsers - which is why we update, if you choose not to update, then you have to accept the risks. No site today is coding to protect the user of IE4 from his\her self. Any code run by the browser is client side, and will not penetrate your server.

Comment: While it may not penetrate the server directly, executed client side code such as can still potentially pass session ids and/or any other data accessible through the DOM to an external source, in theory allowing session hijacking or information leakage - these are the main risks of XSS, which are typically client side attacks. I'm getting the feeling that there is no real way to detect this.

Comment: The standard way this is solved is using a separate domain. Examples include dropboxusercontent.com, googleusercontent.com or githubusercontent.com . This means malicious content is not able to access things like auth tokens because of the same origin policy.

Comment: @Prinzhorn 2 thank you, that's useful :)